# Use subselects or multiple queries?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm wondering what's best. At this moment I have 3 'activation' codes for certain functionality within our back-end (shop)software. These three codes are checked for validity over 3 queries at this moment. This can also be done by using 1 query with subselects. The point is that in the future more and more codes can be added and what is considered the best practise in this situation? The perspective I'm interested in is reducing load on the DB-server and get the best performance in this scenario. (Indexes are set properly, ofcourse)

Comment: Why don't you benchmark this and know for sure instead of asking someone on the internet?

Comment: Because I'm not only interested in the actual result, but also the opinion/experience from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, almost the only scenario where breaking the query into several makes sence, is when results of some of them is cached. That way the overal permormance of them might be better.

Another scenario might be when you want to move   business logic out of the DB to the application, even though the performance might degrade.

Otherwise, I would use a single query.

Answer (score 0):

One wise query is practically always better, than several queries.

In most cases the best way is to rewrite you queries so that you could be able to retreive the info required with one query.

BTW, subqueries are treated like joins by the internal optimzer, so sometimes it's useful to learn how to write sql queries with joins and staff.

Comment: Not all subqueries can be treated as joins.